# why does my tableview not call didselectrowatindexpath until 2nd touch?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, popviewcontrolleranimated

I have a parent table view with custom rows, each one pushes a view controller with a `tableview` of selectable options that are stored as properties of the **parent view controller**.  My code:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  /*
    CrewPositions *selectedPosition = (self.crewPositionList)[indexPath.row];
    [self.delegate childCrewPositionDidSelect:selectedPosition];
    NSLog(@"child Selected Position: %@", selectedPosition.title);
    [[self navigationController] popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
  */
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    CrewPositions *selectedPosition = (self.crewPositionList)[indexPath.row];
    self.selectedCrewPosition = selectedPosition;
    NSLog(@"self.selectedCrewPosition: %@", self.selectedCrewPosition);
    selectedFlightHistory.crewPosition = selectedPosition;
    NSLog(@"self.selectedFlightHistory.crewPosition: %@", selectedFlightHistory.crewPosition.title);

    [self.delegate childCrewPositionDidSelect:selectedPosition];

    NSLog(@"Popping view to parent");
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

works properly, unfortunately the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` does not get called until after I tap the list of cells a 2nd time.  When I do, it passes the first row, previously selected, to the parent view. Ignore the copious amounts of `NSLog`, just capturing what the variables are doing.

Comment: Yeah - it helps if you read the name of the delegate method you are implementing.

Answer (score 9):

rename your `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` method to `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

it is called on 2nd time because your select another cell and deselect the previous one

Comment: oh my God I am blind!

Comment: you are not the first one made this mistake...

Comment: And you won't be the last - (disclaimer - I've done it a couple of times)

Answer (score 2):

It's happening because you wrote wrong method name. `didDeselectRowAtIndexpath:` is sent when the row is **de** -selected.

So change the method name `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` So that the implementation is for the correct delegate method.

Comment: Don't duplicate answers.